# Isekai about MC leveling up and killing monsters by the skill "dispel"

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am trying to find about this manga, Korean webtoon or manwha, cannot remember; that the first chapter is about the MC in a forest being attacked by a monster that looks like a tiger and he murders it subconsciously by the skill translated as "*dispel*" in English translation, a powerful cheat that he is not aware of how to use properly yet.

If I recall correctly, he can also learn skills of those monsters by eating them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is *Garbage Brave: Isekai ni Shoukan Sare Suterareta Yuusha no Fukushuu Monogatari* or *[Garbage Hero: A Revenge Story of a Hero Who Got Summoned to Another World](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/garbage-brave-isekai-ni-shoukan-sare-suterareta-yuusha-no-fukushuu-monogatari)*. Though everything seems to be just slightly off.

The main character is summoned and has the class 'cook'.  The people who summoned his class think he is useless, so they shove him through a portal into a forest.  There he is attacked be a large cat creature with spots like a leopard.  It nearly kills him, then he uses "*dismantle*", at least that is what it says in the translation I found. This kills the cat creature and he levels up a lot.  Eating the meat healed him, and gave him *night vision* as a skill. He then appraises the meat and sees that different parts of the creature give different skills/stat boosts.

Glancing through, it looks like he tries using magic/other skills in fights, and uses 'dismantle' as a last resort.  This could be where you get that he isn't aware of how to use it properly from.